# Errors with <mat-form-field>. Normal Input works fine, but cant use mat-select with out an error

Tags: html, angular, web

I've had a look at other questions yet none have yielded results.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select matInput placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Basic selector.  I get this error when I run in browser.

1. If 'mat-option' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-option' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this

Had a look around and i've imported the api needed.

```
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select'
```

I also have alot of other Mat Imports

```
import {
 MatInputModule,
 MatMenuModule,
 MatCardModule,
 MatButtonModule,
 MatIconModule,
 MatToolbarModule,
MatExpansionModule,
} from '@angular/material';
```

Yet I'm still getting the error. App working completely fine with regular input such as:

```
    <mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Address</mat-label>
  <input placeholder="eg 221B Baker Street" type="text" 
   name="Address" ngModel required minlength="5" #title="ngModel">
</mat-form-field>
```

Been on this for a day and its a point where I cant progress without fixing it. Any help will be appreciated. 
I wont be able to reply until i get from work. 
thanks again!

Edit: Adding In the entire app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PostDetailsComponent } from './post-details/post-    details.component';
import { PostService } from './services/post.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import {
  MatInputModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
} from '@angular/material';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material'
import { PostCreateComponent } from './post-create/post-create.component';
import { PostEditComponent } from './post-edit/post-edit.component';
import { PostSigninComponent } from './post-signin/post-signin.component';
import { MembershipTypesComponent } from './membership-types/membership-    types.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'list',
    component: PostDetailsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'create',
    component: PostCreateComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'edit/:id',
    component: PostEditComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'membershipTypes',
    component: MembershipTypesComponent
  }
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostDetailsComponent,
    PostCreateComponent,
    PostEditComponent,
    PostSigninComponent,
    MembershipTypesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
   RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatMenuModule,
  ],
  providers: [PostService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can you add the full code for the module where you do the `import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select'` please?

Comment: Did you import int `AppModule`?

Comment: ```import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material'```

Comment: @jack did you check my answer?

Comment: @FatemeFazli. Sorry I just got back from work. I have tried it. still didnt change. Still gave me the same error. I'm here all night if there is anything else i can do

Comment: @user184994 Added the app.module.ts above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `MatSelectModule` into the `imports` array, like so:

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSelectModule
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks thats fixed the error! Its weird I thought I had tried doing that already! its fixed the error but the drop down still doesnt work. Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

you are importing `MatSelectModule` in wrong way, just try:

```
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material'
```

Comment: The docs have it down as `import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';` https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Comment: Same for 5 and 6 https://v5.material.angular.io/components/select/api https://v6.material.angular.io/components/select/api

Comment: the docs are wrong:)) even if in material [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/oonndrrgndk?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.ts) samples it's imported from material.